# Pug: accessing bootstrap from node_modules

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I am using pug to output html which I use for later pdf generation with html-pdf.

My controller:

```
// read file
    var source = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'templates/pdf.pug'), 'utf-8');

    // compile pug template and output html
    var template = pug.compile(source);
    var html = template(data)
```

My template

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Merapi Export
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
  body
    h1 Merapi Export
```

Is there any way to integrate bootstrap directly from node modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you have to set a base dir to your pug template in the options of html-pdf (used to generate the pdf):

```
base: 'file:///'+__dirname+'/templates/'
```

Once this is done you can access bootstrap like this:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='../../../../../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')
```

Answer (score 0):

In app.js

```
app.use(
  "/css",
  express.static(path.join(_dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css"))
)
app.use(
  "/js",
  express.static(path.join(_dirname, "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js"))
)
```

in your pug file

```
link(rel="stylesheet", href="./css/bootstrap.min.css")
script(src="./js/bootstrap.js", defer)
```